# VBAからURLで指定したファイルのタイムスタンプを取得したい

Tags: vba

VBAで、URLで指定したファイルのタイムスタンプを取得したいです。

例
`http://example.com/files/abcde.xlsx`

一度ダウンロードしてしまえばいくらでも取得できるとは思うのですが、ダウンロードする前に確認して、新しくなっているようならダウンロードする処理をさせたいと思っています。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: こちら [pythonでＷＥＢ上に置いてあるファイルのタイムスタンプの取得を行いたい。](https://teratail.com/questions/96163) はPythonの記事ですが、[HTTP の HEAD メソッド](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD) で取得した [HTTP の Last-Modified レスポンスヘッダー](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified) で情報が取れそうなことが書いてあります。ただこちら [vbaとHTTPリスクエストを使用したwebサイトの更新日時取得](https://teratail.com/questions/68751) のように必須じゃないので通知されない場合があるらしいですね。他に参考 [【ExcelVBA】HTTP/HTTPS通信でWebページを取得する](https://qiita.com/nkojima/items/c11f6369f4c32b06c90b)

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。参考にさせていただきました。今後ともよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSXML2.XMLHTTPを使用してヘッダから更新日時を取得する例です。
`Last-Modified`がヘッダに含まれている場合はファイルをダウンロードせずに更新日時を表示します。

コメントと[How to get http response header in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32655302)を参考に実装しました。

```
Sub ボタン1_Click()
    Dim h
    Set h = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    h.Open "HEAD", "http://localhost:8000/Book1.xlsx", False
    h.send
    Dim headers
    headers = h.getAllResponseHeaders()
    If InStr(headers, "Last-Modified") > 0 Then
        MsgBox h.GetResponseHeader("Last-Modified") '通信回数を減らしたい場合はheadersをSplitしてください
    Else
        MsgBox "Last-Modifiedが見つかりません" 
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。サンプルをいただけたおかげで、なんとかできるようになりました。これからも何かありましたら宜しくお願いします。